# Use Git Locally without affecting other TFS users Visual Studio 2015

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

**Background**

I have used git for a number of years and it is my prefered method of source control. Whilst I know that git provides other benefits for the sake of this question I am only interested in the benefit of being able to manage topic branches quickly and easily.

I have recently moved jobs and now I have to go back to using TFS. The team I am working on is not ready to consider using Git however I would like to start using git locally and push to TFS. I know this is supported in Visual Studio 2015 (which is what we use) however I am keen not to impact the TFS repository in any way or affect other users. Also I do not want to confuse the UI, I am very happy using Git from the command line and do not like using git from the team explorer.

I know that if there is a git repository in the solution folder then Visual studio starts trying to get its hooks in automatically. Personally I would prefer Visual Studio to let you decide wheter or not to let it get its hooks in before it does. (We are developers and can handle this degree of complexity and do not need to be spoon fed Microsoft.)

I have used GIT with SVN in a similar way which was relatively painless to set up. Mainly just adding files to the ignore lists of both.

**Questions**

1. If I create a local git repository in my working folder will any of the information about this be passed into TFS. For example are there any files such as the sln file that Visual studio modifies that might then be checked in to TFS. If there is any information passed in to TFS is it possible to prevent or undo this.
2. Is it possible to have Visualstudio and TFS completely ignore the fact that there is a .git folder there, so that I can use git from the command line and maintain my work flow in Visual studio and TFS the same.
3. How should I go about setting up git locally so that it has zero impact on the TFS repository?

Answer (score 0):

Use git-tfs. It has been made for that. Don't try to do in 1 day what other try to do successfully in more than years... (and use recheckin ;-))

Comment: Git-TFS. I am not sure we understand each other. I am trying to ensure that the git integration that already exists in Visual Studio 2015 will not interfere with or be visible to other TFS users in any way. I can use the tools I want locally as long as they do not impact other members o fthe team. before I go down the route of creating a .git folder locally I want to make sure that it will not cause upset to anyone in the team.

Comment: Ah. Ok. So there is no problem (if you have tfs 2015) . Create your git repository inside the TFVC project.

Comment: I have tried this (called git init in the solution folder from the command line ). however, Visual studio has said "hey I have git repository I will change the UI tio use Visual studio git ui". I really do not want this but expect I will have to live with it. If I choose manage connections I can browse the repository and pull remote chagnes using the source control explorer. However when i try to push a shelve set as a test back to tfs (containing a new file only) I get a message box saying the file caonnt be found. Visual studio will not let me connect to TFS when the solution is open.

Comment: To clarify if I open source control explorer in visual studio it closes the solution if I open the solution I lose the facility to interact with tfs source control.

Comment: You are not very clear on what you want to achieve. My first idea was right. Just use https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs